# Is it possible to change the "integral-dependance" tag into "integral-dependence"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'd like to propose to change the tag [integral-dependance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-dependance) into the more used expression [integral-dependence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integral-dependence). Is this possible?

Comment: Since you [seem to know](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/integral-dependance/topusers) about this tag, would you consider editing [tag-excerpt/tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/integral-dependence/info)?

Comment: Another tag which could need some attention from someone knowledgeable in commutative algebra is [formal-completions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17179842#17179842).

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can rename a tag by creative misuse of the tag merge tool. To rename a tag you have to manually retag one question to the new tag, and then merge the old tag into the new one. This has the same effect as simply renaming the tag.

This is usually the better option once there is a significant number of questions in a tag, as the community can only retag one question at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how could I merge the old tag into the new one?

Comment: @user26857 Only a moderator can do that